# How to plot a shape once and stop plotting while another condition is met?

Tags: pine-script

This is the relevant script.

```
lucidSARbullish=L_SAR < close
lucidSARbearish=L_SAR > close
bullishcondition=twohrRSI > 50 and price > lwma[1] and diplus > diminus and macd > signal and hist > 0 and oc == 1 and ruleState == 1 
         and adx > 20 and sqzmombull == true
bearishcondition=twohrRSI < 50 and price < lwma[1] and diplus < diminus and macd < signal and hist < 0 and oc != 1 and ruleState == -1 
         and adx > 20 and sqzmombear == true
```

As it stands, by default, the `plot()` function checks every single bar/period and plots if the condition is true. I want to plot `lucidSARbearish` and `lucidSARbullish` separately as a yellow triangle (below for bullish, above for bearish), but it ends up overlapping with the shapes plotted by `bullishcondition` and `bearishcondition`.

How can I make it so that when `lucidSARbearish` and `lucidSARbullish` are true, it plots the yellow triangle just once, and doesn't plot again while `bullishcondition` and/or `bearishcondition` are true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb, but I still don't exactly know how to have it only plot once then wait for the bullish/bearish conditions to go true to false to plot again. While not necessary, I think it'll be more useful that way.

```
lucidSARbullish=L_SAR < close and bullishcondition==false
lucidSARbearish=L_SAR > close and bearishconditon==false
```